# Print specific number of pattern matches

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I've got a large file in the next format:

```
test.txt
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2
...
```

I want to split the file into several files like:

**file1.txt**

```
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2
...
```

**file2.txt**

```
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2
...
```

I tried with awk to find the pattern:

```
awk'{/patter1/,/patter2/} {print}' $test.txt >> file$a
```

But I can't make it stop on after a specific number of matches. 
I also try `sed` to find the pattern unfortunately with the same result.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: file2.txt must start where file1.txt end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN { n = 1 } { print $0 > "bandera" n } /bandera2/ { n++ }' infile
```

For input file:

```
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2
bander1
...
bandera2
```

It yields:

```
==> bandera1 <==
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2

==> bandera2 <==
bandera1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bandera2

==> bandera3 <==
bander1
...
bandera2
```

---

**UPDATED** (*see comments*):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { n = m = 1 } 
    { print $0 > "bandera" n } 
    /bandera2/ { 
        if ( m == 500 ) { n++; m = 0 }
        m++ 
    }
' infile
```

Comment: thnks that work just fine, one question the increase of n can be conditional like if n -eq 500 then n++, since i need to put in one file several match pattern im trying insted of n++ something like this: { if [ $n -eq 500 ];then n++} so bandera1 can record like 500 pattern match

Comment: @user2619593: I've updated the answer. I use an additional variable until `500` that flags when to increment the other that is used in output file names.